# /sbin/nologin issue with msys2 on Windows 10

Tags: msys2

I have just installed MSys2 (https://msys2.github.io, msys2-x86_64-20150916.exe) on my Windows 10 computer.

Once installed, the terminal is launched. But as soon as I stop it and relaunch it, I get the error: "Failed to run /sbin/nologin: No such file or directory".

Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out why Bash is trying to run `/sbin/nologin`.  Check your Windows home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\Joe`) for files like `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, and `.bashrc`.  Inspect those files and find which one is calling nologin.

If that doesn't help, try creating an empty file in `C:/msys64/sbin/nologin`, or wherever you actually installed MSYS2.  An empty file would be a valid shell script and run without errors.

If the error is non-fatal you might consider just ignoring it.